# Define variables in styled-components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

Is it possible to define a variable inside a `styled-components` component?

Hopefully the code below (not working) shows what I'm after:

```
const Example = styled.div`
  ${const length = calc(vw - props.someValue)}

  width: ${length};
  &.disable {
    width: ${length};
  }  
`
```

Answer (score 2):

This code will not work, as far as I understand ***Template Literal's*** guidelines.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Template literals are those backticks that wraps the code you have after the `div` .

> const Example = styled.div`**here**`

Let's say:

```
const num = 10;
console.log(\`The number I saved in a variable is ${num}\`);
```

The output log would be: `"The number I saved in a variable is 10"`

Inside Template literals you can have an *expressions*. Declaring a variable is not possible inside because its a statement:
http://2ality.com/2012/09/expressions-vs-statements.html

So this question is more about the core of  **Javascript** then `styled-components` in itself.

Answer (score 0):

A possible workaround using CSS variables but no ie support.

```
const Example = styled.div`
  --length: calc(vw - props.someValue)

  width: calc(var(--length));
  &.disable {
    width: calc(var(--length));
  }  
`
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently wanted to do something like this. But in my case, I had to compute new var with the use of props only and not with vw.

I achieved this by defining a short function.

```
const getLength = (baseValue, someValue) => {
   // you can do any complex or multiline calculation here
   return baseValue - someValue;
}

const Example = styled.div`
width: ${(props) => getLength(props.baseValue, props.someValue)};
&.disable {
width: ${(props) => getLength(props.baseValue, props.someValue)};
}  
`
```